# NextJS router.push() does nothing, however location.href works

Tags: next.js13

I'm trying to use router.push("/video-scene") but the browser just "swims", never gets to "video-scene". However, if I use location.href="/video-scene" it works as expected. I would like to use router because of router.prefetch(). Am I missing something here? Please see my code below:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

useEffect(() => {
    router.prefetch("/video-scene");
  }, [router]);

const newSession = await fetch("/student-session/start", {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, studentId: student._id }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          if (json.res.acknowledged) {
            Cookies.set("sid", json.res.insertedId, {
              expires: cookieExpiration(),
            });
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          clientLogger("error", "/home - fetch() - starting student session", {
            error: err.message,
            stack: err.stack,
          });
        });

      if (newSession) {
        console.log("New Session: ", newSession);
        router.push("/video-scene");
      }
```